# Geopackage: Table created with python doesn't show up in QGIS's DB manager

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, geopackage, dbmanager

In my python script I want to create a table in a Geopackage that will hold new values to be joined on existing data later. Anyway for table creation I use this:

```
def creaTable(name,sqlcon):
    c = sqlcon.cursor()
    c.execute('''CREATE TABLE "{}"
             ("fid" INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                "kgez" TEXT NOT NULL,
            "anz" INTEGER NOT NULL,
            "distEig" INTEGER NOT NULL)'''.format(name))
    c.execute('''CREATE TRIGGER "trigger_insert_feature_count_{0}" 
        AFTER INSERT ON "{0}" BEGIN UPDATE gpkg_ogr_contents 
        SET feature_count = feature_count + 1 
        WHERE lower(table_name) = lower('{0}'); END '''.format(name))
    c.execute('''CREATE TRIGGER "trigger_delete_feature_count_{0}"
        AFTER DELETE ON "{0}" BEGIN UPDATE gpkg_ogr_contents 
        SET feature_count = feature_count - 1 
        WHERE lower(table_name) = lower('{0}'); END '''.format(name))
    sqlcon.commit()
```

The table and triggers are there when opened with some DB-browser however it wont show up in QGIS DB manager.

What am I missing out on? Or is there a simpler way to create a non spatial table for QGIS from scratch?

Comment: Does your code add new rows into gpkg_contents and gpkg_geometry_columns?

Comment: Well, now it does. Thanks. Feel free to post an answer. But I still do wonder about the amount of pythoncode necessary to create (and fill) a table...

Comment: Well, it is not about creating and filling in a table. You did success with that, didn't you? But there is a reason why GeoPackage has a few metadata tables with foreign keys, consraints and triggers as they appear in the Figure 1 in http://www.geopackage.org/spec121/. If you want to write less python I guess that gdal.VectorTranslate could help with it https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-module.html.

Comment: Feel free to write an answer yourself.